# sql server inner join query not executing

Tags: sql-server

what is wrong with this query?
these are the tables i am using-

```
create table PS3_Vehicle 
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    DealerID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    VehicleID varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    VehicleName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Capacity BIGINT NOT NULL    
);

create table PS3_VehicleBooking
(
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
  BookingID varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  VehicleID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  StartDate date NOT NULL,
  EndDate date NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE PS3_Dealer(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary KEY,
    DealerID varchar(255) NULL,
    DealerName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ContactNo varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    NoOfVehicles bigint NOT NULL,
    CommittedDate date NOT NULL
);

SELECT DealerID, PS3_Vehicle.VehicleID, VehicleName, StartDate, EndDate
FROM PS3_Vehicle
INNER JOIN PS3_VehicleBooking ON PS3_Vehicle.VehicleID != PS3_VehicleBooking.VehicleID AS W
INNER JOIN PS3_Dealer ON W.DealerID = PS3_Dealer.DealerID
  AND CommittedDate > GETDATE();
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: In your 1st Inner join you have != in your "ON" clause ??? Also there is Column Name Ambiguity for DealerID in Select statement as this column is present in more than one table with the same name

Comment: those dealerid's vehicle id which are not present in vehiclebooking table but i want in result start date and end date columns also containing nothing

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do it with a simple `LEFT JOIN` between `PS3_Vehicle` and `PS3_VehicleBooking` where `PS3_VehicleBooking` has no match for that vehicle:

```
SELECT v.DealerID, v.VehicleID, v.VehicleName, vb.StartDate, vb.EndDate
FROM PS3_Vehicle v
LEFT JOIN PS3_VehicleBooking vb ON v.VehicleID = vb.VehicleID
WHERE vb.VehicleID IS NULL
```

This will give you the vehicles that are not present in `PS3_VehicleBooking`, which makes `startDate` and `endDate` always `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT w.DealerID, w.VehicleID, w.VehicleName, b.StartDate, b.EndDate
FROM PS3_Vehicle w
INNER JOIN PS3_VehicleBooking b ON w.VehicleID != b.VehicleID 
INNER JOIN PS3_Dealer d ON W.DealerID = d.DealerID
  AND CommittedDate > GETDATE();
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f5c0/6

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT v.DealerID, v.PS3_Vehicle.VehicleID, v.VehicleName, b.StartDate, b.EndDate
FROM PS3_Vehicle v
Left JOIN PS3_VehicleBooking b ON v.VehicleID = b.VehicleID
INNER JOIN PS3_Dealer d ON v.DealerID = d.DealerID
Where b.VehicleID is null
AND d.CommittedDate > GETDATE()
```

Will give you all unbooked vehicles and infor about the dealer who hasn't dealt them..

Ps when you start doing queries like this, fully qualify all your names with aliases or table names, makes things much easier for the next developer.

Oh and startdate and enddate will always be null in this query, and so are pointless.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT D.DealerID, V.VehicleID, V.VehicleName, vb.StartDate, vb.EndDate
FROM PS3_Dealer D LEFT JOIN  PS3_Vehicle V 
ON D.DealerID = V.DealerID 
LEFT JOIN PS3_VehicleBooking vb
ON V.VehicleID = VB.V.VehicleID
WHERE vb.V.VehicleID IS NULL
AND CommittedDate > GETDATE();
```